# Show that $\lfloor(1+\sqrt{3})^{2n-1}\rfloor$ is divisible by $2^n$

Tags: number-theory

> Show that $\lfloor(1+\sqrt{3})^{2n-1}\rfloor$ is divisible by $2^n$ where $n$ is a positive integer.

We have \begin{align*}\lfloor(1+\sqrt{3})^{2n-1}\rfloor &= (\sqrt{3}+1)^{2n-1}-(\sqrt{3}-1)^{2n-1}\\&=\dfrac{(4+2\sqrt{3})^n}{1+\sqrt{3}}+\dfrac{(4-2\sqrt{3})^n}{1-\sqrt{3}}\\&=2^n\left(\dfrac{(2+\sqrt{3})^n}{1+\sqrt{3}}+\dfrac{(2-\sqrt{3})^n}{1-\sqrt{3}}\right).\end{align*} Thus we must show that the second term is an integer. How can we continue?

Comment: How do you get your first equality?

Comment: @GTonyJacobs intuitively it's that the second term is less than 1, and the difference is an integer. But that's not rigorous and I would also like to know if this fits into some formalism.

Comment: Since asking, I thought of that, too. I'm not sure what isn't rigorous about it, honestly. If $x-y\in\mathbb{Z}$, and $0\leq y<1$, then $x-y=\lfloor x\rfloor$, because it's an integer greater than $x-1$ and less than $x$.

Comment: I do think it's wild that odd powers of $(\sqrt3+1)$ form a geometric sequence of numbers whose fractional parts form another geometric sequence. I guess that happens every time we have a quadratic irrational number greater than $1$ whose conjugate is in the interval $(0,1)$. Numbers are awesome.

Answer (score 4):

Set $x_n=\frac{(2+\sqrt{3})^n}{1+\sqrt{3}}+\frac{(2-\sqrt{3})^n}{1-\sqrt{3}}$. Show that $x_1, x_2$ are integer and $x_{n+2}=4x_{n+1}-x_{n}$ holds, thus by induction $x_n$ is an integer for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$.

Answer (score 2):

Hint: $1 \pm \sqrt{3}$ are the roots of $t^2-2t-2=0\,$, so $\;a_{n} = (1+\sqrt{3})^{n}+(1-\sqrt{3})^{n}$ is the solution to the recurrence $a_{n+2}=2a_{n+1}+2a_{n}\,$ with $a_0 = a_1 = 2$.

Answer (score 0):

$$(\sqrt{3}+1)^{2n-1}-(\sqrt{3}-1)^{2n-1}$$
Take n = 2
$$(\sqrt{3}+1)^{3}-(\sqrt{3}-1)^{3}$$
Look at, binomial expansion of the powers
First term,
$$ 3\sqrt(3) + 3*3 + 3\sqrt(3) + 1 $$
Minus second term,
$$ 3\sqrt(3) - 3*3 + 3\sqrt(3) - 1 $$
Gives
$$ 2*3*3 + 2 $$
So you get only every second term. Generalize to higher powers and get a general formula. See that it divides by $2^n$